# TTL expired in transit

Tags: linux, networking, debian, routing, gateway

I bought a server with 4 ip addresses that need to be configured manually

- `yy.zz.159.7/23 (gw yy.zz.156.1)`
- `yy.zz.159.8/23 (gw yy.zz.156.1)`
- `yy.zz.159.13/23 (gw yy.zz.156.1)`
- `xxx.144.29.243 (gw xxx.144.28.1)` main ip address

I added a subinterface ifcfg-eth0:1/2/3 for each one and this is my route table :

```
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xxx.144.28.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
yy.zz.156.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         yy.zz.156.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         xxx.144.28.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

When i ping on the added ip addresses i get `TTL expired in transit` message, from my researches i think there is an infinite loop in my route table, can anyone please point out the problem here?

Comment: Can you make sure the addresses actually show up in `ip addr`? Although based on the `traceroute` output for your addreses I would actually guess that the problem is with the provider, not your configuration.

Comment: yes i am sure, i wanted to make sure my configuration is correct before coontacting the provider, thank you so much for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed your addresses, ran a `traceroute` (well, mtr) to all four of them, and while it shows a loop, it's ping-ponging between two addresses that look very much like a point-to-point link between two routers. The same loop also happens when trying to ping/traceroute various other addresses from the subnet, so it's probably "normal" for not-yet-assigned addresses at this provider.

From that I would guess that the problem is with your server provider – *they* don't have the correct routes pointing the extra addresses to your server.

---

Meanwhile, your own routing table seems normal, and isn't missing anything obvious. Although that's not the whole routing table – there are entries that the obsolete *route* command doesn't see. If you directly assign an IP address to an interface (such that it shows in *ip addr*), this creates a hidden /32 route that tells the OS to always consume the packets and this takes priority over regular subnet routes.

So if you have verified that the addresses are in `ip addr`, the loop generally won't be your fault.

---

What you should check now is whether you even **receive** the packets at all. Use a packet capture tool such as *tcpdump*:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 "icmp"
```

While it's running try to ping the server's addresses. If you had a loop, tcpdump would show a storm of "ICMP Echo" packets for every single ping attempt. On the other hand, if it *doesn't* show any echo packets at all, then the problem is with your ISP (i.e. the server hosting company) – they haven't actually routed the addresses to your server correctly.

Comment: You were right, i contacted the provider and now it's working thanks again :D